# Restirct items shown by django-restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a book model in my Django app and each book has an author. My models are

```py
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Comment(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(book)
```

in my app each user can comment on a book and each author can login and see the comments. I wanted to filter comment by the book for the author and each author could only see its own books in the filter items. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the comments of books by an author `author` with:

```
comment.objects.filter(book__author=author)
```

With *`author`* a a `User` object of the author. If the `author` wrote multiple books he/she will see all comments on his/her books.

> **Note**: The name of a model usually starts with an uppercase, so `Book` instead of <s>`book`</s>, and `Comment` instead of <s>`comment`</s>.